# A coin is tossed 6 times. What is the probability that the no. of heads in the first 3 throws

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A coin is tossed 6 times. What is the probability that the no. of heads in the first 3 throws is the same as the number number in the last three throws?

To be honest, I don't know how to tackle this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it into **disjoint** events, and add up their probabilities:

- The probability of $\color\red0$ heads in each part is $\frac{\binom{3}{\color\red0}}{2^3}\cdot\frac{\binom{3}{\color\red0}}{2^3}$
- The probability of $\color\red1$ heads in each part is $\frac{\binom{3}{\color\red1}}{2^3}\cdot\frac{\binom{3}{\color\red1}}{2^3}$
- The probability of $\color\red2$ heads in each part is $\frac{\binom{3}{\color\red2}}{2^3}\cdot\frac{\binom{3}{\color\red2}}{2^3}$
- The probability of $\color\red3$ heads in each part is $\frac{\binom{3}{\color\red3}}{2^3}\cdot\frac{\binom{3}{\color\red3}}{2^3}$

---

Hence the overall probability is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{3}\frac{\binom{3}{n}}{2^3}\cdot\frac{\binom3n}{2^3}=\frac{5}{16}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $X$ be the number of heads in the first three rolls, and $Y$ be the number of rolls in the last three. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent and follow what kind of distribution?

Further, we are asked to calculated
$$P(X = Y) = \sum_{k = 0}^3P(X = k, Y=k).$$